# Nginx reverse proxy - "Error 403 forbidden"

Tags: docker, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, alfresco, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've installed the [Docker version of Alfresco](https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/community/install/containers/docker-compose/) that use a Nginx as reverse proxy.

My problem is that (I think) **the NGINX proxy refuse PUT and DELETE http calls** if I do them from browser (i tried with RESTer, a Firefox extension and from an Angular application), but it work if I do them from Postman.

I don't understand why. Someone can help me?

The http example call is:

```
PUT http://localhost/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/c8968ba1-8574-4682-84f1-916c089ee3a4/content?majorVersion=false
```

This is the header of a http request sent from Angular:

```
 PUT http://localhost/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/c8968ba1-8574-4682-84f1-916c089ee3a4/content?majorVersion=false HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Authorization: Basic cHJvcG9uZW50ZTpwcm9wb25lbnRl
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 187388
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarymFAdm79OPkw9aAZo
Cookie: ALFRESCO_REMEMBER_ME=1
Host: localhost:4200
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

And this is the server answer:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 403, statusText: 'Forbidden', url: 'http://localhost/alfresco/api/-default-/public…4682-84f1-916c089ee3a4/content?majorVersion=false', ok: false, …}
```

But if I do the same request from postman it works-

I attach here some screenshot.
These are the header parameters:
[image: POstman header parameters]

And this the right answer from the proxy:
[image]

---

I paste below the differences between RESTer e Postman, the first has the black background and the second the grey.
RESTEr add automatically some other fields. Differences are highlighted in yellow.

[image: Angular vs Postman logs]

Log reports this:

```
172.18.0.1 - proponente [03/Sep/2023:14:23:38 +0000] "PUT /alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/665c5fcb-19b1-4d12-9c03-5f916e753628/content HTTP/1.1" 403 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0"
```

Is there a log (in Docker installation) where I can find more info?

Thanks.

Someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: If you compare the request headers between Postman and Angular: what's the difference?

Comment: What do you get in nginx logs on the container when you witness a rejected request?

Comment: I've added informations to my post, if someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the logs, as suggested in https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/community/install/containers/docker-compose/#check-system-start-up.

For example, you can use the following command:

```
docker logs -f --tail=25 docker-compose-alfresco-1
```

Here, **docker-compose-alfresco-1** is the container name for Alfresco.

In your example, I noticed that you are trying to update the content of two different nodes: c8968ba1-8574-4682-84f1-916c089ee3a4 and 665c5fcb-19b1-4d12-9c03-5f916e753628.

Do both nodes have the same permissions for the user?

As the API documentation states (https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#/nodes/updateNodeContent), a 403 status code means "Current user does not have permission to update nodeId."

Comment: Yes, they have.
If I do this from Postman all works, but if I do from a web app it doesn't work.

Thanks.